# iPhone - detecting circle movements

Tags: iphone, ios, cocoa-touch, ipad

I have an area where the user can draw using a finger. This area contains an object that I want the user to be able to rotate it clockwise or anti-clockwise. My idea is to offer the user the whole screen to control the object. I mean, if the user starts to describe clock wise finger movements in a circle pattern, the object will rotate on that direction. If the movements are anti-clockwise the object will rotate the other direction.

So, the idea is to detect if the finger is describing circle movements, clockwise or anti-clockwise and the amount of angle. This has to be real-time, I mean, as far as the user is rotating the finger object is rotating.

I have seen apps doing something like that, where the user draws a shape and boom, the app replaces the clunky shape drawn with a pretty one. In essence the app detected that a circle, a triangle, etc., was drawn and replace that gesture with a real pretty shape.

How do I do this kind of stuff? I am just interested in circle movements.

Can you guys point me the direction?

thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the "hough transform for circle detection". Here is a good [blog post](http://basic-eng.blogspot.com/2006/02/hough-transform-for-circle-detection.html) to start with:

Comment: I don't know which programming language was that, but looks like Klingon to me... sorry.

Comment: It was in Matlab, but the concept should carry over to any language. Here is an implementation in OpenCV (C) which should look more familier.  http://blog.weisu.org/2007/12/opencv-detect-circles-with-hough.html